# Why can't I access the user other objects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I creating a blog application. I trying to access every detail of a post. In the model, I've added the user as `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` with `ref: 'User'`. In the frontend part, I'm using react with redux while the `console.log` the post details it's showing me everything even the `user_id` but I'm unable to access the user objects like name, etc. Please check this code to tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Please If you need any other details, please comment.

### SINGLE POST VIEW PAGE

```
    import { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
    import { listPostDetails } from '../actions/postActions';
    import Category from '../components/Category';
    
    const SinglePost = ({ match }) => {
      const postId = match.params.id;
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const postDetails = useSelector((state) => state.postDetails);
      const { post } = postDetails;
    
      console.log(post);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listPostDetails(postId));
      }, [dispatch, postId]);
    
      return (
        <div className="pt-5 pb-3">
          <ToastContainer />
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                <img
                  src={post?.img}
                  alt={`${post?.title} pic`}
                  className="singlePostImage"
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={9} className="singlePostHeading">
                <h2>{post?.title}</h2>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                <small>Author: {post?.user?.name}</small> <br />
                <small>Posted on: </small>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              </Col>
              <Col md={3} className="singlePostCategory">
                <Category />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default SinglePost;
```

### Here are models Please check if there are any mistakes in the models

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Please Author is required'],
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    img: {
      type: String,
    },
    isLiked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    isDisLiked: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    likes: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
    disLikes: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
    comments: [
      {
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
        },
        text: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        name: {
          type: String,
        },
        pic: {
          type: String,
        },
        date: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
      },
    ],
    categories: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'modified_at' },
  }
);

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

export default Post;
```

### User Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, ' Please provide a name'],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, ' Please provide a email'],
      unique: true,
      match: [
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
        'Please provide a valid email',
      ],
      lowercase: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 6,
      required: [true, 'Please add a password'],
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: true,
    },
    pic: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default:
        'https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'modified_at' },
  }
);

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```